# Proving set equivalence

Tags: elementary-set-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $S =\{[12],[3]^{-1},[13][4]\}$ and $T= \{[6^{16}],[24]+[67],[-158]\}$ be subsets of $\mathbb Z_{17}$. I am trying to prove $S=T$

So far I have $S =\{[12],[6],[1]\}$ since $[a^{-1}]=[b] \iff ab \equiv 1(mod\,x)$ and $T= \{[1],[6],[12]\}$

But I am not sure if this is sufficient. Does anyone know?

Comment: This is very much sufficient. I don't see what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you arrived at the right conclusion, you may want to be a bit more verbose in your presentation.

- Since $6 \cdot 3 \equiv 18 \equiv 1 \mod 17$, we have $[3]^{-1} = [6]$.
- Since $13 \cdot 4 \equiv 52 \equiv 1 \mod 17$, we have $[3]\cdot [14] = [1]$.

This yields $S = \{[12],[6],[1]\}$ and we may also note that these elements are pairwise distinct.

Similarly

- $6^{16} \equiv (6^2)^8 \equiv 2^8 \equiv (2^4)^2 \equiv (-1)^2 \equiv 1 \mod 17$ yields $[6^{16}] = [1]$.
- $24+67 \equiv 7 + 16 \equiv 23 \equiv 6 \mod 17$ implies $[24]+[67] = [6]$.
- $-158 \equiv -158 + 170 \equiv 12 \mod 17$ implies $[-158]=[12]$ and thus

$T = \{[1],[6],[12]\}$.

Therefore $S = T = \{ [1], [6], [12] \}$.